# How can I configure tags in the whitelist of permitted tags for "Limited HTML" in Drupal 7's editor?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, theming

How can I alter / expand the whitelist of permitted tags for "Limited HTML" in Drupal 7's editor?

Or, what may or may not be the same question:

On http://ludditeorthodox.com I have a block of text which I would like to precede with an image. As noted on another question, I copied and test-modified page.tpl.php to page-front.tpl.php, but the test `<div style="background-color: silver">` was not showing up on the homepage. Given that the homepage is presently displaying a basic article as desired, what is the best way for me to add an image above the article text?

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your question directly:**

Configuration > Content Authoring > Configure (the format)

At the bottom under "Filter settings" there should be a list of allowable  HTML tags. Just add in

**For a better solution:**

Create an image field and display that above the text. The advantage is that Drupal will handle the uploading and storing of the image.

or install the following modules.

- http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg
- http://drupal.org/project/media

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add an image above the article text is **using an extra field of type "image"** and configure the display to be above the text field.